# Menu vertical com filtro dentro do sub-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-3

Gostaria de fazer um filtro dentro do sub-menu, filtrando o próprio menu conforme vai digitando vai exibindo os relacionados.

A ideia seria [semelhante a este link](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panel-table-with-filters-per-column). No final do meu menu tem o sub-menu chamado de loja ou adm.

**Exemplo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/cetnzp4x/1/

Comment: Juntei os comments aqui na pergunta. Espero não ter esquecido nada...

Comment: @Welguri tente fazer algo com o seletor [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Só que ele é _case sensitive_, usar o `lowercase` como você fez não vai ajudar.

Comment: Então @KaduAmaral tentei me baseá no exemplo que faz a busca na tabela http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panel-table-with-filters-per-column ... para mim esta ainda complexo demais. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um filtro desse tipo:

```
$('#filter').on('keyup', function(){

    var dataFilter = $(this);
    var valorBusca = dataFilter.val();
      var contaLetras = valorBusca.length;
       if (contaLetras >= 1) {
           filterData(valorBusca);
       } else {
        $('.navbar-nav li a').parent().show();  
       }

 function filterData(data) {

        $('.navbar-nav li a').each(function(iIndex, sElement) {
            $(sElement).parent().hide();  
            if (sElement.innerHTML.indexOf(data) !== -1) {
                 $(sElement).parent().show(); 
             }  
        });
} 

function retiraAcentos(palavra) {
    var com_acento = 'áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ';
    var sem_acento = 'aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC';
    var nova='';
    for(i=0;i<palavra.length;i++) {
        if (com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1))>=0) {
            nova+=sem_acento.substr(com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1)),1);
        }
        else {
            nova+=palavra.substr(i,1);
        }
    }
    return $.trim(nova).toLowerCase();
}

});
```

Aqui está o JSFiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1L8Lc86s/1/**

Aqui tema versão completa:
**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1L8Lc86s/5/**